# Plus equals operator error

Tags: javascript, ajax, operators

Hello so I'm trying to get the += to increase value of balance. I now understand that in java script use += is to pass by reference, but how can I use it to pass by value.

```
alert("Welcome to the Online Bank Teller");

        var balance = 100.00;
        var amount;
        var run = true;

        do{

            var pick = prompt("Make a selection...\n1-Check Balance, 2-Deposit, 3-Withdraw, 4-Quit");

            if(pick == 1){alert("Your balance is: $" + balance.toFixed(2));}
            else if(pick == 2){ 
                    amount = prompt("Enter the amount you want to deposit: $");

                    if(amount > 1000){alert("You can only enter up to $1000 per deposit!");}
      Right here--->balance += amount;
                    alert("Your new balance: $" + balance.toFixed(2));
            }
            else if(pick == 3){ 
                    amount = prompt("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: $");

                    if(amount > balance){alert("Amount exceeded account balance!");}
                    else if(amount > 500){alert("The max you can take out is up to $500 per withdraw!");}
                    else if (amount <= balance){
                            balance -= amount;
                            alert("Your new balance: $" + balance.toFixed(2));
                    }                               
            } 
            else if(pick == 4){run = false;}
            else{alert("Not a valid choice!");}

        }while(run)
```

How can I get it to alter the value inside of the variable when the user enters a new deposit.

I get

```
Your balance is: $10022
```

instead of

```
Your balance is: $122
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Whay is it being tagged with `java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `parseInt()` function to each amount which is getting from prompt

```
amount = parseInt(prompt("Enter the amount you want to deposit: $"), 10);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/suman_bogati/t67FJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a string to a number with `+=` operator produces a string.

`prompt()` returns a string, hence you need to convert the return values to a number:

```
balance += +amount;
```

Or use `parseFloat()` to convert values. Though I can't understand how you'd get anything alerted, since strings haven't `toFixed()` method, and hence the `alert()` in your code is supposed to trigger an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
balance = parseInt(balance) += parseInt(amount);
```

Balance and amount are strings, so for example:

Adding the string '50' to the string of '3' woul make '503'

Adding the float value of '50' to the float value of '3' would make '53'

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `parseInt` function that has already been mentioned, there are some "quick&dirty" ways to do it:

```
amount = 1 * prompt("Enter the amount you want to deposit: $");
// get'S converted because * is only defined on numbers

amount = +prompt("Enter the amount you want to deposit: $");
// converted because unary + is only defined on numbers
```

and a couple of other, less common ones.